# how to insert null Datetime in database with entity framework codefirst

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

my model includes a nullable datetime property.*Im using CodeFirst*

```
 public DateTime? GoDate { get; set; }
```

I would like to insert a nullvalue into that field but EF inserts the usual 00/00/0001 date instead of null, which also gives me an error.

*im using microsoft sql server 2012.*

```
DateTime? date = null;
var entity = new Model()
                {
                    GoDate = date
                };

DataContext.Models.Add(entity);
DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

give me the error.

The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

That is because sql server datetime cant have 00/00/0001, which EF automatically generates once it inserts a null datetime into the database.

I want to insert null into the db.

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server? When you say it "gives [you] an error", what error do you receive? Are you using DB first or code first?

Comment: Where is the code for insert??

Comment: Using Nullable<DateTime> or DateTime? should make it accept NULL.  Is the column in the database marked as "NOT NULL"?

Comment: in the database the field is marked as NULL.Again the problem is that entity framework generates a datetime value of 00/00/0001 if the datetime is null and the sql server doesnt have 00/00/0001 for date.I need to stop entity generating that default value.

Comment: Check the generated SQL when doing `SaveChanges()` and post it here.

Answer (score 17):

> EF inserts the usual 00/00/0001 date instead of null

There's nothing *usual* about it. Left to its own devices, EF 6.1 inserts `NULL`.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var DataContext = new StackOverflowContext();

            DateTime? date = null;
            var entity = new Model()
            {
                GoDate = date
            };

            DataContext.Models.Add(entity);
            DataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    class Model
    {
        public int ModelId { get; set; }

        public DateTime? GoDate { get; set; }
    }

    class StackOverflowContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Model> Models { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

It's most likely your mappings or database schema are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can just set like this:

```
var entity= new Model
{
    GoDate = (DateTime?) null
}
DataContext.Models.Add(entity);
DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

I think it is a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this in your model. then sending null from your controller will work fine.

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

**Notice the `?` after DateTime.**

Comment: I notice the "?" _after_ the DateTime, but not before?

Answer (score 1):

You Can use this :

```cs
Nullable<DateTime> date=null;
var entity = new Model()
{
    GoDate = date
};

DataContext.Models.Add(entity);
DataContext.SaveChanges();
```